# How to run a exported selenium ide test suite intoTestNG using eclipse

Tags: selenium-ide

I  recorded a test suit using Selenium IDE .I am testing a simple login page with its test cases.I exported the test suite as Java/TestNG/Remote Control.Now I am using eclipse to open my converted test suite.One more doubt is there i converted test suite in Java/TestNG/Remote Control but why its importing junit packages

**login.java**

```
package com.datadriven;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class LoginTestsuit {

    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTestSuite(TC-1.1.1.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(TC-1.1.2.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(TC-1.1.3.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(TC-1.1.4.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(TC-1.1.5.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(TC-1.1.6.class);
        return suite;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());
    }
}
```

TC.1.1.1 to TC1.1.6 are my test cases in test suite.I dont know how to use relate all this test cases in converted test suite.I am getting following error please refer this link to see error screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH7zJ.png

**TC-1.1.1**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="selenium.base" href="http://localhost:8080/Banking/" />
    <title>New Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
    </thead><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>open</td>
        <td>/Banking/</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>name=sub</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pause</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>5000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
        <td>Enter username!</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**TC-1.1.2**

```
</thead><tbody>
    tr>
        <td>refresh</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>id=fname</td>
        <td>Jackk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>name=sub</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
        <td>Enter password!</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

**TC-1.1.3**

```
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=fname</td>
    <td>Jackk</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=Lname</td>
    <td>1234567</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>name=sub</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
    <td>Incorrect UserName or Password</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

..and so on

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
       Check the version of Selenium IDE you are using, It should be 2.9.0,
       Make it sure that you have TestNg integrated with eclipse, else follow these [steps][1],

       If you still face the same issue then just remove the junit lib files from your script 
       and replace them with testng lib 
       and also do the same for the Junit annotations by replacing testng annotations
```

Comment: I am using selenium IDE 2.9.0. I tried with replacing junit library into testng library .I am getting following error Multiple markers at this line
 - TestSuite cannot be resolved to a type
 - TestSuite cannot be resolved to a type
 - Line breakpoint:LoginTestsuit [line: 12] 
  - suite()

Comment: can u send me example of converted selenium test suite into testNG and eclipse.I am testing a simple login page